# Determine if solution to linear system exists

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to determine *only* if a solution to a linear system of equations exists. I have been using `LinearSolve`, which works fine, but it solves the system as well. Is there another more efficient method for only checking the existence of a solution?

Comment: For a one-off problem where nothing special is known about the system beforehand, actually solving the equation gives you access to the most efficient methods. In *MMA*, `LinearSolve` is very fast and (for general-purpose work involving non-square matrices) provides solutions an order of magnitude faster than other methods using (say) `MatrixRank`, `RowReduce`, or `Minors`. As an example of how extra info can help, if it's known the coefficient matrix is orthogonal, then you already know a solution exists.

Comment: There is some important discussion in the comments to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**==== Update ====**

Please consider important discussion in the comments.

**==== Original answer ====**

If the matrix `m` has determinant zero, then there may be either no vector, or an infinite number of vectors `x` which satisfy `m.x == b` for a particular `b`. This occurs when the linear equations embodied in `m` are not independent. If you are interested only in well-defined systems, then, generally, confirming that you have a non-zero determinant is faster:

```
m = RandomReal[1, 1000 {1, 1}];
b = RandomReal[1, 1000];
```

Some timing tests:

```
Mean @ Table[LinearSolve[m, b]; // AbsoluteTiming, {30}][[All, 1]]
```

> 0.0712654

```
Mean @ Table[Det[m]; // AbsoluteTiming, {30}][[All, 1]]
```

> 0.0571327

Comment: I suspect the performance trade may fall the other way depending on the size and character of the system. The most efficient methods for solving large systems usually do not involve directly computing the determinant.  (LinearSolve automatically picks an efficient method..)

Comment: @george2079 the benchmark i posted is pretty general and the system is pretty large. Of course, some specific systems may show a different result.

Comment: This has two problems. For approximate matrices it is not numerically sound. Far safer is to check singular values for zeros below some tolerance. Else you can get a false positive, that is, a claim of solvability when the matrix is singular or nearly so. The other problem is that (to be cont'd)

Comment: ... in the exact case, e.g. integers, Det computation can be slower than actual solving. Example:In[22]:= n = 2^10;
mm = RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
vec = RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, n];
In[27]:= AbsoluteTiming[sol = LinearSolve[mm, vec];]
Out[27]= {11.3440000, Null}
In[28]:= AbsoluteTiming[Det[mm] == 0]
Out[28]= {53.7370000, False}

Comment: A third problem is that computing a determinant works only when there are exactly as many equations as variables. There is a generalization (implementable via `Minors`), but it is likely to be relatively inefficient (there can be a lot of minors to compute and store).

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov There is no need to delete this answer. You can edit your answer to make a note of Daniel's and whuber's concerns and address them if you can. You can always improve the answer — deleting is a nuclear option. Probably also alert the OP to your updated answer.

Comment: @rm-rf good idea, will do.

Comment: @Daniel, "check singular values for zeros" - or check the condition number of the matrix, as in my answer.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, a condition number check is fine too. As best I recall those are estimated for the various norms supported, but in ways that tend to reliably show when a matrix is effectively singular.

Answer (score 10):

The upshot of Vitaliy's note to check for a zero determinant is that

1. A matrix with inexact entries that is supposed to be singular (e.g. because it is rank-deficient) might not necessarily give a determinant that is exactly zero, due to roundoff.
2. A tiny determinant does not necessarily imply that the matrix is "nearly" singular. (Conversely, just because a matrix does **not** have a tiny determinant doesn't mean that `LinearSolve[]` won't have a problem handling it.) See for instance [this answer I wrote at scicomp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1330).

Thus, to **safely** determine if a matrix is singular, you can do any of two things:

1. Check if the output of `NullSpace[]` is an empty list. If its output on your matrix is `{}`, the matrix is nonsingular; otherwise, the number of null vectors it produces (the *nullity*) gives an indication of how rank-deficient it is.
2. Use the undocumented function `` LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[] ``. Checking for singularity is as easy as seeing if its output on your matrix is $\infty$, in which case, your matrix is singular. As a bonus, if the value returned is huge, but not necessarily infinite, you still have a good warning sign that `LinearSolve[]` might treat your matrix as singular even if it isn't. See any good numerical linear algebra book (e.g. Golub/Van Loan) for details.

Comment: P.S. The nice thing about `NullSpace[]` is that it can flexibly deal with both exact and inexact matrices; IIRC it uses Gaussian elimination in the exact case, and the (safer) singular value decomposition in the inexact case.

Answer (score 0):

Odd. If you get a solution, you *know* that a solution exists, isn't it? Anyway, what you can do is suppress the output by adding a `;` to your input. Then

```
LinearSolve[{{4, 8}, {9, 2}}, {x, y}];
```

returns nothing, while

```
LinearSolve[{{4, 8}, {9, 2}, {0, 0}}, {x, y, z}];
```

returns

> ```
> LinearSolve::nosol: Linear equation encountered that has no solution.
> ```

Comment: `LinearSolve` carries out all of the steps of solving the system when all I need is a yes/no to whether or not a solution exists. So will `LinearSolve` be the most efficient way of doing this regardless?

Comment: @A.R.S. - My guess is that the steps to check if there's a solution are the same as calculating the solution. *(disclaimer: I'm not a mathematician, so you may wish confirmation from the Real Guys :-))*

Comment: @A.R.S., what mathematical "magic" do you think might be done to determine whether a linear system has a solution that would be substantially different from actually attempting to find solution? Except in special cases, as others have noted, in each situation some sequence of transformations will need to be done (whether row reduction or something more sophisticated like a matrix decomposition).

Comment: @murray - Maybe he's thinking about something like primality testing, where you can say a number is composite in a second, but may need a couple of months to find the factors.